# python define replica set configuration

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm writing the script to setup the replaset for mongo in python.
The first part of the script starts the processes and the second should configure the replicaset.

From the command line I ussually do:

```
config={_id:"aaa",members:[{_id:0,host:"localhost:27017"},{_id:1,host:"localhost:27018"},{_id:2,host:"localhost:27019",arbiterOnly:true}]}
rs.initiate(config)
rs.status();
```

And then I'm looking from rs.status() that all members are initialized
I want to do the same in python script.

In general i'm looking for a good reference of setup scripts for mongodb (also sharding). I saw the python script in their site, it is a good start point (but it only for single machine and sinle node in replSet). I need to setup all on different machines.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `rs.initiate` (without the `(config)`) the shell tells you which command it would run. In this case, it would be:

```
function (c) {
    return db._adminCommand({replSetInitiate:c});
}
```

In python this should be something like:

```
>>> from pymongo import Connection
>>> c = Connection("morton.local:27017", slave_okay=True)
>>> d.command( "replSetInitiate", c );
```

With `c` being your replicaset configuration. http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.command has some more information on calling commands.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Derick. Here are some remarks to your answer. **'replSetInitiate'** is DBA command. Run it agains **'admin'** database. As here:

```
conn = Connection("localhost:27017", slave_okay=True)
conn.admin.command( "replSetInitiate" );
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the output of rs.status in pymongo we can use like this

```
def __init__(self):
    '''Constructor'''
    self.mdb=ReplicaSetConnection('localhost:27017',replicaSet='rs0')


def statusofcluster(self):
    '''Check the status of Cluster and gives the output as true'''
    print "We are Inside Status of Cluster"
    output=self.mdb.admin.command('replSetGetStatus')
```